# Phonegap html5 video full screen breaks back button behavior

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7, phonegap-cli

I'm using Phonegap in combination with Framework7.

I have a really strange issue. I'm using html5 video tag to stream video. Streaming works perfectly fine.

Issue appears when I go fullscreen. After exiting full screen and pressing back button applications closes instead of going on previous screen.

If I play video and don't go fullscreen it will work normally and go back to previous screen.

This is the code that I have:
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        alert('backbutton');
        if (mainView.activePage.name=='index'){
            navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure want to exit from App?", onConfirmExit, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
            function onConfirmExit(button) {
                if(button==2){ //If User select a No, then return back;
                    return;
                }else{
                    navigator.app.exitApp(); // If user select a Yes, quit from the app.
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            mainView.router.back();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

The alert in the code will not appear if I go fullscreen, exit from fullscreen and press back.

Is this some bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code? keep in mind that you must do some modification to listen to the `back` event, there is already a callback named `myApp.onPageBack(pageName, callback(page))` http://framework7.io/docs/page-callbacks.html

Comment: I already shared the relevant code. And in that code I'm listening for "backbutton" event. I don't want to listen when page is going back, I want to listen when user press back button. And code above works fine, but it stops working after entering and exiting fullscreen video.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry man, this is weird, and I'm interested. I meant to share the full code so I can test in on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in an Ionic2 app which uses a custom video player plugin. When I switch the player to full screen and back, Ionic's hardware back button functionality stops working: the app closes immediately on clicking the hardware back button instead of popping the next view from Ionic's navigation stack.

I fixed my problem using the solution suggested here: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/148

I had to override dispatchKeyEvent() in CordovaActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (this.appView != null) {
        View webview = this.appView.getView();
        if (webview != null) {            
            return webview.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is a hack, of course, since a core Cordova file has been modified, but I have yet to find a better solution.